# Could not find or load main class ...commons-logging-1.1.1.jar while running a spring batch job from linux command line

Tags: java, linux, spring-batch

I am trying to run a simple spring batch job from linux command line using the following command:

$PATH_TO_JAVA -cp $PATH_TO_JAR/dependency-jars/*;$PATH_TO_JAR/SpringBatchExample.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner file:resources/spring/batch/jobs/job-read-files.xml readMultiFileJob

But getting the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class ...dependency-jars.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar file is present in $PATH_TO_JAR/dependency-jars folder. Please advise.